# Translating from logical to physical addresses

Tags: operating-system

Assume a virtual memory configuration with a page frame of size 2K, virtual address of space of size 32K and physical address space of 16K. With a page mapping of your choice, determine the actual physical address corresponding to the virtual address 0573H.

I am new on this topic. please, anyone can explain the easy way to mapping from logical address to physical address?

Comment: It's wherever you have the first (or zeroth) page mapped to.

Comment: Mr Pradip nice question. So, you had it your solution from here. nice :) keep learning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Page size =2K=2^11

Virtual Address Space = 32K=2^15

Physical Address Space =16K=2^14
```

[image]

Here Virtual Address  is :

```
0573H ==> 0000 0101 0111 0011

Page# = 0000 ==>0

Page offset = 101 0111 0011 ==> 573
```

By consulting page table we can get the frame number to which this page has been assigned to, and compute actual physical address as shown in this fig.